# Слайдера изображений на главной для PrestaShop 1.7

Tags: slider, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, free

Нужен качественный бесплатный модуль слайдера изображений на главной для PrestaShop 1.7

Такие есть вообще в природе кроме стандартного?

Comment: можна поискать в шаблонах безплатных - был помню у Лео

Comment: у них лицензия на один домен, нужна лицензия без ограничений и желательно GNU

Comment: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/791545-free-module-responsive-touch-slider-for-prestashop/ - а этот не подходит ?

Comment: klifort, Спасибо, слайдер хороший, но судя по описанию он работает только под версии 1.5 и 1.6.